# How to improve the accuracy of my prediction models?

Tags: r, predictive-models, accuracy, rapidminer

First, I am an absolute beginner in this field of science.

For my research task, I need to use mobile sensor data to determine a user's keypresses (similar to this: [Keystrokes Inference Attack on Android: A Comparative Evaluation of Sensors and Their Fusion](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266088297_Keystrokes_Inference_Attack_on_Android_A_Comparative_Evaluation_of_Sensors_and_Their_Fusion)).
What I did:

1. Collect the sensor data for each sensor (timestamp, x, y, z)
2. Collect the key data (timestamp-down, timestamp-up, key)
3. Aggregated over the keys to extract statistical features for the keys like min, max, mean, root-mean-square,... (see image)[image]
4. Imported it to `RapidMiner`
5. Applied Algorithms

In the different papers I read, they usually used a combination of k-cross-validation and/or bagging with Decision Trees/Forests.

I did the same, but while they achieve up to 95% accuracy, the best I got was 55% +/- 14%.

My sample size is about the same as theirs, I extracted the same features (and added even some more). I also applied Feature Selection Algorithms.
But I cannot get even close to 90%.

Since I am a beginner in this field, I feel like I am missing out something fundamental. So, I hope you can provide me with advice.

Comment: Would be better to copy/paste the actual code rather than uploading an image of it...

Comment: I also think that you are confusing some concepts when you say: " they usually used a combination of k-cross-validation and/or bagging with Decision Trees/Forests" - These are very different things... Bags of words are a way to build features, Decision Trees or Forests are models to represent the data, and k-cross validation is only a way to compute the accuracy of the approach (it is not part of the model, only a way to quantify how well it works). What are the algorithm that you applied?

Comment: @Eskapp I initially did copy/paste the code, but the formatting was broken. I also didn't mean bag-of-words, but Bagging where you run multiple iterations of a base learner (like decision tree) with varying training set. I tried kNN, Decision Trees, Random Forests, Decision Trees + Bagging, kNN+ Bagging, Naive Bayes

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the precision :) I had a look at the paper, it seems that they used algos implemented in Weka directly. By experience, similar methods implemented in 2 different libraries can sometimes give different results (mostly because of internal parameters that you cannot control). Bad results can also appear if your data are too noisy. Maybe try to add a denoising step at the beginning and an outlier removal step. Because 1 outlier with a very big value in your case now for instance, "destroys" your max feature and maybe the mean feature too and can have repercussions everywhere.

Comment: Thanks. Can you recommend a common denoising step?

Comment: I am not sure if there are some specifications for the specific type of data you are using. A Gaussian filtering with a right tuning for the standard deviation usually does the work. But it will not remove the outliers, you will need a separate process for this...